# Can you legally use Ubuntu on laptops that have hardware which is not certified for use with Ubuntu (Asus for example) ?

Tags: hardware, asus

Can a company use Landscape management tool on its Asus laptops/computers for example ?

Comment: Landscape and Ubuntu are not the same. Which one is it?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Ubuntu ! I am asking about Ubuntu. Is it legal if a company use Ubuntu on its Asus computers, even though Asus computers have a hardware which is not certified for use with Ubuntu (for now at least). And can Canonical provide support for those computers ?

Comment: Yes, [Canonical can provide support](https://www.canonical.com/services)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah sure, you can legally install Ubuntu on almost anything except for a potato. I've got Ubuntu installed on my Asus laptop, and everything worked right out of the box.

Comment: Insert obligatory Portal 2 reference here.

Comment: https://m.imgur.com/gallery/0S5spVm